# Boost Load_Construct_Data for template class

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I am attempting to serialize a class with no default constructor, according to the boost documentation is very clear that override methods are needed.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors

The class i wish to serializeis is iteself a template class.

```
////Overrides for non-default constructor used in Node<NU
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Archive>
        inline void load_construct_data(Archive & ar, Feature<96> * t, const unsigned int file_version)
        {
            // retrieve data from archive required to construct new instance
            int id;
            ar >> id;
            // invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance of Feature
            ::new(t)Feature<96>(id);
        }

        template<class Archive>
        inline void save_construct_data(Archive & ar, const Feature <96> * t, const unsigned int file_version)
        {
            // save data required to construct instance
            ar << t->id();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make these methods generic? In order to use a Feature< T >?

I cannot see this in the documentation or here on StackOverflow. Thoughts?